# making jquery post() updates - checking if connection failed/timeout

Tags: jquery, ajax

For a simple web page, I'm doing regular calls to a php script via jQuery's post() to make a change to the database and then get some updated info back.

Sometimes these calls fail but there is no notification.

Can someone advise me of the best method to use for error checking? so I can display a message if the update fails on account of connection dropout, timeout or anything else that could happen and be checked for explicitly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off - Make sure you are utilizing the success event callback with its response Object to rule out any server-side errors.

```
$.ajax({
   //... other ajax options
   success: function(response){
      alert(response);
   }
});
```

Your php script is *essentially* echoing a response to this success function.  It could be a simple string "success", "fail" or even a [**JSON**](http://json.org/example.html) / [**XML**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) string

Second...

You can set a timeout option to rule out those errors:

```
$.ajax({
  //...other ajax options...
  timeout: 5000 //5 second timeout
});
```

Third...

You can use the error event callback for any exceptions...

```
$.ajax({
   error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
   //handle errors here
   }
});
```

From the [**jQuery docs on ajax**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

**Error:**

> A function to be called if the request
>   fails. The function is passed three
>   arguments: The XMLHttpRequest object,
>   a string describing the type of error
>   that occurred and an optional
>   exception object, if one occurred.
>   Possible values for the second
>   argument (besides null) are "timeout",
>   "error", "notmodified" and
>   "parsererror". This is an [**Ajax Event**](http://docs.jquery.com/Ajax_Events).
>   This handler is not called for
>   JSONP requests, because they do not
>   use an XMLHttpRequest.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this link. It explains how to deal with timeout:

http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1500-Catching-Timeout-Errors-With-jQuery-Powered-AJAX.htm

Ignore the initial part. Check out the jQuery code.